# Create dynamic diagonal gradient using javascript for html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way to create a diagonal gradient doing something like this?  My attempts only give me a vertical or horizontal

```
 _canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 _stage = _canvas.getContext('2d');

 var gradient = _stage.createLinearGradient(0, 0, buttonEndX, buttonEndY);
 gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
 gradient.addColorStop(1, "blue");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work fine. Do you call `context.fillRect()` after previously setting `context.fillStyle = gradient` and are your `buttonEndX` and `buttonEndY` variables set to meaningful values?

```js
var buttonEndX = 100, buttonEndY = 100;

_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
_stage = _canvas.getContext('2d');

var gradient = _stage.createLinearGradient(0, 0, buttonEndX, buttonEndY);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "blue");

_stage.fillStyle = gradient;
_stage.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

The above code renders as (Chrome 48):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have it correct, Patrick. [This codepen](https://codepen.io/dallas/pen/BzoLqq) shows an example of how the code you have should potentially render. Which brings up the question of what are your `buttonEndX` and `buttonEndY` values? Maybe try something as simple as a `console.log(bottonEndX)` to make sure that those values are what you expect them to be.